# prove that the square of a coeficient 0f chromatic polynomial of a graph is greater than equals to product of adjacent coeficients

Tags: graph-theory

According to this [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/color-me-polynomial-20190813/), the claim is true. How do we prove this?
Can you give an outline of the proof?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on chromatic polynomials led me to this reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4749

Comment: @user 42493: Quoting from the article you referenced in your question: "Polynomials can tell us about the structure of graphs, and graphs can tell us about the structure of their associated polynomials. It was a search for structure that led June Huh to prove Read’s 40-year-old conjecture about chromatic polynomials. The conjecture says that when we list the coefficients of a chromatic polynomial in order and ignore their signs, a particular condition is satisfied: Namely, the square of any coefficient must be at least the product of the two adjacent coefficients.

Comment: @user 42493: Hence it's a research-level problem.

Comment: Yeah... Good luck bridging the gap between a Quanta article and a technical paper solving the problem using algebraic geometry. Quote from the end of the introduction: "As will be clear from below, the present work is heavily indebted to other works in singularity theory, algebraic geometry, and convex geometry."

Comment: I think the abstract of the paper gives a reasonable (but admittedly brief) outline of the proof: "The proof is obtained by identifying $ \chi _G(q)$ with a sequence of numerical invariants of a projective hypersurface analogous to the Milnor number of a local analytic hypersurface." (BTW, see https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-2012-00731-0 for the published paper — it appears to be available without a subscription.)

Comment: You post a solution and I'll accept